# Tlsharp ConnectAsync

Tags: c#, telegram

Когда я вызываю client.ConnectAsync() моя программа останавливается.
Если я пишу Console.WriteLine(client.IsConnected) я получаю **true**.
Однажды моя программа запустилась и я смог аутентифицировать и ввести код. Больше у меня не получалось.

Comment: а что вы хотите сделать? что вы делаете? какой у вас код? может привидите код и сформулируйте вопрос заного?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, часть кода, а желательно -- целиком метод, в котором вызывается ConnectAsync, потому что из Вашего вопроса совершенно непонятно во-первых, что Вы хотите сделать, во-вторых, как именно Ваша программа "останавливается": она бросает исключение, останавливается поток или что происходит?